# Étale morphism has all its Deck transformation homotopic to identity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, complex-geometry, covering-spaces

Is there an example that étale morphism (of degree $d,d<\infty$) $\pi: X\rightarrow Y$, s.t. all its Deck transformations homotopic to $Id_X$,except the trivial one, where $Y$ is general Enriques surface over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

Any finite cover between two nonsingular elliptic curves would do the job.

Comment: thanks, I should rule out those cases like abelian varieties. I care more about nonabelian surfaces. is there such kind of examples. I have modifyed my question

Comment: @FengHao: A trivial modification would be to multiply elliptic curves $E, E'$ by a smooth projective curve $C$ of genus $\ne 1$: $X=E\times C, Y=E'\times C$ and then use the product map as your covering. You should  think more about the question you are really asking. Do you want surfaces of general type maybe?

Comment: Yes I just came up with thise question. acturally I meet a problem with $Y$ to be general enriques surface. However, I really don't want to make this question to restrictive. Right now I know K3, but it fails. And also, by covering tricks, we know there should be not so much etale covers for such $Y$.